# How to fetch rows with similar tags as an other row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an array named $tagArr where I store tags. The tags are stored in database separated by `spaces (' ')`. 
This is how I fetch tags from DB.

```
$tags=$row["tags"];
$tagArr =  (explode(" ",$tags));
```

After this, I have elements in the array $tagArr at indexes

```
$tagArr[0], $tagArr[1], $tagArr[2], ...., $tagArr[n].
```

`$lim` contains the number of elements in the array. I find it by using

```
$lim = count($tagArr);
```

Consider this eg.
Column '`tag`' contains the string: `apple orange grapes`

after exploging it into array, the indexes will contain,

```
$tagArr[0] : apple
$tagArr[1] : orange
$tagArr[2] : mango
```

Now I have the other SQL query in which I choose other pages with similar tags. Here is the incomplete query,

```
$sql="SELECT title FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE '% <what will i place here?> %'";
```

I was using the following, which will only find posts with the first tag

```
$sql="SELECT title, link, img FROM news WHERE tags LIKE '%$tagArr[0]%'";
```

How do I do it properly so that I can fetch posts with any of the tags in it? That is any post with tag apple **OR** orange **OR** mango.

Comment: You can use find_in_set() i think http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Comment: It would help if you could show us sample table data along with what you plan to query.  By the way, storing CSV data in your table is a generally bad idea.

Comment: Can I know why? In my case the tags are posted by the admin of the website. User does not have the option to input tags into the DB.

Comment: @PareshGami What will be the variables I pass into the function in my case?

Comment: You have to change the separator to comma if you want to use finf_in_set(). But before doing so, pls read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: But I would use fulltext index and search if you are stuck with this data structure.

Comment: @RiyaAnna You can pass string by delimiter. like find_in_set('orange','pink');

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: have you tried regex in query? check out answer and let me know if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in Query.

```
$row = "apple mango";
$tag_ex = '('.implode("|",explode(" ",$row)).')';

//$tag_ex will be >>  (apple|mango)
//which you can use as regex in query.to match apple Or Mango in column

$sql = sprintf("SELECT title, link, img FROM news  WHERE (tags REGEXP %s)",$tag_ex);
```

> After $sql looks like,
>
> SELECT title, link, img FROM news WHERE (tags REGEXP (apple|mango))
>
> which select records containing apple or mango in tags column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really normalise your data structure, storing delimited list of values in a single field invites troubles like this one. For details see the answers to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) question here on SO.

If you cannot change the table structure for whatever reason, then use [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) in place of like, since the tags will be separate words.

1. Create a fulltext index on the tags field:

   ```
   alter table posts add fulltext index ft_tags (tags)
   ```
2. Use `match(...) ... against(... in Boolean mode) ...` [fulltext search function in Boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to search for tags:

   ```
   select * from posts where match(tags) against ('apple mango')
   ```

Note: you do not have to split the contents of the `tags` field into an array, since the `against()` takes a list of words separated by space as parameter.

There are 3 things you need to pay attention to:

1. `against()` can only take a string literal as parameter, so if you want to search for similar posts for multiple sets of tags, then you have to repeatedly run the query. If you normalised your data, this would not be an issue.
2. Fulltext index has a minimum word length parameter, which is set to 3 for innodb, and 4 for myisam tables by default. If you have tags shorter than the minimum word length, then you have to reduce the minimum word length **before** creating the fulltext index.
3. Fulltext indexes also use a list of stop word - words that are too common in the text (such as `the` in English) and these words are not indexed. If a tag is on that list, then you have to take it off.

All these are described in the linked MySQL documentation along with the instructions how to change them.